# Understanding Complex LookUp Function in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, lookup

I am in the process of converting a excel macro into a Python script for ease of running.However i have come across a column that requires a lookup function, i am familiar with basic Vlookups and Hlookups but i cannot find a similar formula to the following. it seems to produce a matrix like function.please see below the formula in question

```
=+IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,'Table1'!A:A,1,FALSE)),"",LOOKUP(2,1/('Table1'!A:A='Table2'!A1),'Table1'!C:C))
```

I have no problems with the first part of the formula simply if error in the vlookup then display nothing, and if not then carry onto the second section. it is this second section  which is causing me issues.

any help is greatly appreciated

Many thanks!

Comment: It would return the last row-index of `Table1'!A:A` where value `='Table2'!A1` and returns the value from that row-index from `Table1'!C:C`. So basically a `MATCH` function but bottum-up. In fact, the first part can simply go: > `IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/('Table1'!A:A='Table2'!A1),'Table1'!C:C),"")`